# associating HTML form fields

Tags: html, forms

How do I link multiple `input` elements in a form so the server knows that two values are related?

Let's assume we have separate fields for first and last names, for multiple people on a single page:

```
<input name="firstNames" value="John">
<input name="lastNames" value="Smith">
...
<input name="firstNames" value="Jane">
<input name="lastNames" value="Doe">
```

When POSTing that, the server eventually has the following data:

```
firstNames = ["John", "Jane"]
lastNames = ["Smith", "Doe"]
```

So we can determine the respective names by index:

```
person = firstNames[i] + lastNames[i]
```

Is there a better way than relying on the order? (Is that even reliable?)

Comment: It is reliable. You process data later on server side.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** : **This is language specific**

Upon further searching, some languages (ASP) allow you to get at the data as a CSV string. So you'll need to add further context to your question. However, the array method still works in all languages.

You can't rely on the order in PHP. If two HTML form elements have the same name the last one overrides everything else (in PHP at least).

Just use arrays.

```
<input name="firstNames[0]" value="John">
<input name="lastNames[0]" value="Smith">
...
<input name="firstNames[99]" value="Jane">
<input name="lastNames[99]" value="Doe">
```

You could also use empty `[]` empty braces as well.

**EDIT**

Copy paste the code below to see the behavior in PHP.

Down voters : I'd really be interested in knowing where this would *not* be the case (in a different language)

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action='test.php' method='post'>
        <input name="firstNames" value="John">
        <input name="lastNames" value="Smith">
        <input name="firstNames" value="Jane">
        <input name="lastNames" value="Doe">
        <input type='submit' value='Go'>
    </form>
</body>

</html>

<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    var_dump($_POST);
}
```

Comment: That's not true. It depends on the parser being used to interpret the request on the server-side - but if that can't handle names of the same name, I'd consider it broken.

Comment: Sorry, I hit submit too soon - have amended my comment. I can't find the relevant part of the spec right now, but multiple `INPUT`s with the same name are perfectly valid. Using array notation is an abomination IMHO.

Comment: @AnC it's perfectly vaid. But the problem is that it cascades. I don't speak for any other language, but I know that this is the case in PHP

Comment: No offense, but I don't consider PHP or Java to be of reference value when it comes to web standards.

Comment: @AnC after your comment, I did some searching. Apparently ASP allows you to get at the data as a comma separated string. Thanks for the heads up, I'll update the answer to reflect the language

Comment: I appreciate that. FWIW, in Python or Node, parsing works as described in my OP.